# Permission denied (publickey) when connecting to EC2 via SSH on Mac Mavericks

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I read the SO on [Permissions error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179427/permissions-error-when-connecting-to-ec2-via-ssh-on-mac-osx), but still can't get pass publickey issue.  Could you look at my log and tell me what else I need to do to fix this issue?  BTW, I've already chmod 600 my keypair, too.  I really appreciate your help.

```
(molaenv)van@mavericks:~/webdev$ ssh -v -i ~/webdev/molakeypair.pem ec2-user@ec2-54-86-32-54.compute-1.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-54-86-32-54.compute-1.amazonaws.com [54.86.32.54] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/van/webdev/molakeypair.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/van/webdev/molakeypair.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 8f:c8:b1:6d:5a:7c:fa:10:95:46:d4:34:63:17:b5:bd
debug1: Host 'ec2-54-86-32-54.compute-1.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/van/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/van/webdev/molakeypair.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: You may have better answers at http://serverfault.com/ Having said that, it looks like your private key is wrong for the machine you're connecting to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the OS running on your EC2 instance ?

For Amazon published AMI, we are using `ec2-user` for Amazon Linux and Red Hat.
On Ubuntu, the default user is `ubuntu`
On Suse, the default user is `root`

For Community AMI, you have to check with the AMI creator what user is configured with your public key.

Comment: And sometimes for some AMIs the default user is `root`

Comment: thank you ! - Answer edited to include your feedback